# Is convergence in distribution transitive?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove that a sequence of statistics $s_n$ is asymptotically normal.

So far I've managed to show two things concerning $s_n$ and a second statistic $s_n^*$:

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} |s_n - s^*_n| = 0$.
2. $s^*_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma_s)$

My question is: what conditions are necessary (if any) to conclude that since $s_n \to s_n^*$ and $s_n^*$ converges in distribution to a centred normal distribution, that $s_n$ is also asymptotically normal?

The statistics in question are the corrected sample standard deviation $s_n$ and the uncorrected sample standard deviation $s_n^*$ taken from a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$.
Here, the underlying sample $X_i$ is iid but non-normal.

Comment: In what sense does $|s_n-s_n^{*}|$ tend to $0$?.

Comment: By the Slutsky's theorem, if $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ and $Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} c$, where $c$ is a constant, then $X_n + Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X+c$. Now if the condition 1 is in the sense of either almost-sure convergence, convergence in probability, or convergence in distribution, then you can apply Slutsky's theorem to conclude that $s_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_s^2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 1) you mean that $s_n-s_n^{*} \to 0$ almost surely (or just in probability)  then it is true that $s_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma_s)$. This can be proved using characteristic functions: $E(e^{its_n}-e^{its_n^{*}})=E(e^{its_n}(1-e^{it(s_n^{*}-s_n)}) \to 0$ by DCT and convergence in distribution follows from this. Actually, $s_n-s_n^{*} \to 0$ in distribution  implies $s_n-s_n^{*} \to 0$ in probability so the conclusion holds even in this case.

Comment: Hi Kavi, thanks for your explanation using characteristic functions, that makes a lot of sense and the use of dominated convergence theorem has also served as a good example for me!